# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected single-quoted string "</li> "

Tags: php, html, wordpress, xampp

Trabajando con Wordpress me he encontrado con el siguiente error a la hora de crear el HTML para la página representándolo en el fichero functions.php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido de este fichero functions.php donde se produce el problema es el siguiente:

""
$mostrar_cursos = 'cursos'; //slug de la página
$table_cursos = 'wp_cursos'; // nombre de la tabla

```
if (is_page($mostrar_cursos)){
    global $wpdb;   

    $items = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `$table_cursos`");
    $result = '';

    // nombre de los campos de la tabla
    foreach ($items as $item) {
    
            $result .= '
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mt-4">
            <div class="card shadow">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1714208/pexels-photo-1714208.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <ul class="list-inline mt-3">
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>'.$item->organizador_nombre '</li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> June 22, 2020</li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-dark my-2" href="#" role="button">Ver más...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }

    $template = '
    <div class="container mb-4">
        <div class="row">
        {columna}
        </div>
    </div>';
    return $content.str_replace('{columna}', $result, $template);
}
```

""

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe y cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en la mala concatenación de las variables, en tu codigo tienes esto

```
<li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>'.$item->organizador_nombre '</li>
```

cuando lo correcto seria esto

```
<li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>'. $item->organizador_nombre . '</li>
```

Comment: Tienes razón, era por la concatenación, muchas gracias por la ayuda!